# Cobra: how to set flags programmatically in tests

Tags: testing, go, cl, go-cobra, cobra

I'm using `cobra` to build a CLI and want to simulate a command being run with different sets of options/flags. I've been trying to figure out how I can use the cobra APIs to set flags within my test but haven't really gotten it yet.

I have this:

```
// NewFooCmd returns a cobra.Command fitted to print output to the buffer for easier testing.
buf := &bytes.Buffer{}
cmd := package.NewFooCmd(buf)

cmd.Execute()

// some validations on the content of buf
```

So far the closest thing I've found is:

`cmd.Flags().Set(name string, value string)`

...but this doesn't seem right because while the names of flags are all strings, they don't all take strings as values. Also it just doesn't seem to work even if I have an `int` flag and pass `string(1)`.

Is there something simple I'm missing here?

Comment: is it https://github.com/spf13/cobra ?

Comment: Yes that’s the cobra package I’m using

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the `(c *Command) SetArgs(a []string)` [function](https://github.com/spf13/cobra/blob/4dab30cb33e6633c33c787106bafbfbfdde7842d/command.go#L202) for this. The fact that some of your arguments are integers or booleans doesn't matter here - after all, that's what a user will be entering on the command line!

The `(c *Command) DebugFlags()` [function](https://github.com/spf13/cobra/blob/4dab30cb33e6633c33c787106bafbfbfdde7842d/command.go#L1100) can be used when you're developing the test to ensure that the flags you're passing are being interperted properly, too.

My integration tests with Cobra tend to end up looking like this:

```
...

cmd := cli.RootCmd()
buf := new(bytes.Buffer)
cmd.SetOutput(buf)
cmd.SetArgs([]string{
    "--some-flag",
    fmt.Sprintf("--some-string=%s", value),
    fmt.Sprintf("--some-integer=%d", integer),
})
err := cmd.Execute()

...
```

Comment: Thanks! Part of the obstacle this cleared up was being able to see that "args" and "flags" are actually both args - just parsed differently.

Comment: When one of the flags is a persistent flag from the parent, .SetArgs doesn't register the flag for some reason. Any idea?

Comment: @dugong did you find a solution? I'm stuck with the same problem

Comment: @MohamedYasser sorry it's been a while I don't remember what I have done.

Comment: @dugong No problem. I'll go with `os/exec` for now. Thank you.